# Copy two SQLite Database in asset folder in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

For the last few days I've been trying to copy two databases in the asset folder, but could not get any success.

One database I managed to copy and access it. But the second one, I need your help.

Comment: Whats the problem with second database..? Why don't you carry out the same steps you used to copy the first one..?

Comment: You should add some more info like the code that fails & the logcat output of the error. It's not possible to see what went wrong in your code.

Comment: @Mudassir  can i use same database helper class for second one ..?

Comment: Yes you can. For this, you have to implement the helper class as non-singleton.

Comment: Mehul,are you using diffrent method as with first.what issue you are facing copying data in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);// Path to the just created empty db
String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases   /(datbasename).sqlite");
// transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
{
myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
}
//Close the streams
myoutput.flush();
myoutput.close();
myinput.close();
}
```

Do this for your second database.